# VBA Function is Extremely Slow to Perform the Task

Tags: excel, vba

I have number of data in the Sheet where i have been using these function to delete the rows by matching the criteria and it is extremely slow to perform the task.

I hope to get some help to make it faster. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

If this can be converted into 1 code it will be great help.

```
       Sub MyList()
    
    Dim Listing     As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    
    LastRow = Function1.GetLastFilledRowNo(Listing)
    
    For RowNo = LastRow To 9 Step -1
        SKU = Format(Listing.Cells(RowNo, 4), "0000000")
        
        RowNoActive = Function2.GetRowNo_BySku(SKU)
        
        If RowNoActive > 0 Then
            Listing.Rows(RowNo).Delete
        End If
        
    Next RowNo
End Sub


Public Function GetLastFilledRowNo(Sht As Worksheet) As Long
    GetLastFilledRowNo = Sht.Columns(1).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
End Function


Public Function GetRowNo_BySku(FormattedSku As String) As Long
    GetRowNo_BySku = Function3.GetRowNoSearchOneColumnByString( _
                     Sheet1, FormattedSku, 2)
End Function


Public Function GetRowNoSearchOneColumnByString(SheetName As String, StringToFind As String, ColumnName As String) As Long
    
    On Error GoTo GetRowNoSearchOneColumnByString_Error
    
    Dim StrFormula  As String
    GetRowNoSearchOneColumnByString = WorksheetFunction.Match(StringToFind, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Range(ColumnName & ":" & ColumnName), 0)
    
    Exit Function
    
    GetRowNoSearchOneColumnByString_Error:
    GetRowNoSearchOneColumnByString = 0
End Function
```

Comment: Well you should turn off calculation and screenupdating. If that is not enough make sure you collect all your rows to delete in a variable using `Union()` and delete them at once in the end (this will be faster than deleting each line separately).

Comment: Yeah you are right. This thing is causing the problem.

Comment: See my answer below, this should give you a significant boost.

Comment: How many rows of data do you have, and how many of those would typically be deleted?  How many rows in the other lookup sheet?

Comment: Sir, Almost 24K rows and the records that deleted are more than 2K and other sheet has almost 5K data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should turn off calculation and screenupdating. If that is not enough make sure you collect all your rows to delete in a variable using `Union()` and delete them at once in the end (this will be faster than deleting each line separately).

```
Sub MyList()  
    Dim Listing     As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    
    LastRow = Function1.GetLastFilledRowNo(Listing)

    Dim RowsToDelete As Range  ' collect all rows

    For RowNo = LastRow To 9 Step -1
        SKU = Format(Listing.Cells(RowNo, 4), "0000000")
        
        RowNoActive = Function2.GetRowNo_BySku(SKU)
        
        If RowNoActive > 0 Then
            ' don't delete here just collect all rows to delete
            If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set RowsToDelete = Listing.Rows(RowNo)
            Else
                Set RowsToDelete = Union(RowsToDelete, Listing.Rows(RowNo))
            End If
        End If
    Next RowNo

    ' if there is something collected then delete 
    If Not RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
        RowsToDelete.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

If all that doesn't get it faster significantly, the issue is probably that you run the `Match` method on every row (which just takes a lot of time and cannot be avoided). You can just test if reading the whole data into an array and performing the match on that array makes it faster. But for that you would need to change the entire design of your code.

Comment: Yes i also assumed that the Match function can be the reason which makes the whole process very slow. But you added a twist thank you let me check.

Comment: Thank you @Pᴇʜ its working faster than before but still i think Match function could help more as you stated. If it does not bother than please give me one more favor with the Match functions. thank you.

Comment: @Arham you probably won't get rid of the match function. You can just try to run it on an array of your data instead of the cells. Your question is too unclear to answer in detail how to do that, but you can google how to use arrays instead of cells to improve speed. There are a lot of tutorials for example: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-working-with-arrays.htm If you get stuck you can open up a new question for that showing what you have tried.

Comment: thank you very much @Pᴇʜ  for this favor.